# Stacktrace from dispose or destructor is incomplete

Tags: c#, destructor, idisposable

I have an abstract class where a constructor opens an sql-connection, that gets closed in the dispose-implementation. (The dispose maybe is called somewhere in a destructor of an superclass)

My stacktrace is just this:

```
internal error .net framework data provider 1 (translated)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.PrePush(Object expectedOwner)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.PutObject(DbConnectionInternal obj, Object owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.CloseConnection(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Close()
   at Framework.Data.DataAccessBase.CloseConnection() in C:\Development\Source\Libraries\Framework.Data\DataAccessBase.cs:Line 304.
```

Line 304 from this class is:

```
private void CloseConnection()
{
    try
    {
        if (_sqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            _sqlConn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

(I just added the `catch (Exception e)` to get the stacktrace, I want to remove it later, when I fixed the error)

And the only usage of private `CloseConnection` is in the `Dispose(bool disposing)`-method. But where can I get more of that stacktrace? The superclass, where the Disposed is called (or the destructor)?

Or maybe you have a hint, what's the problem with the stack-trace? I read a few stackoverflow-articles about this error-message but I need to find the source - but the stack-trace is not very helpful..

**edit:** here is my dispose of DataAccessBase:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!_disposed)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_sqlConn != null)
            {
                CloseConnection();
                _sqlConn.Dispose();
            }
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's possible that this got called from a Finalizer for the class, which means it got called from the garbage collector.

Comment: @MatthewWatson yep that's possible. is there any way to get more info about finalizer calls/garbage collector? there are ~100 classes that derive from that Base-class :D

Comment: Is `DataAccessBase` your class? Can you write a finalizer for it and put some debug output into it, so at least you can verify that's what's happening (you could output `this.GetType().FullName` to find the exact type)? However, it's quite hard to find out *where* it's not being disposed, since you won't have a meaningful stack trace for the finalizer call from the GC.

Comment: @TimSchmelter because I don't inherit directly from SqlConnection. I have a field with an instance of SqlConnection. And the Dispose simply calls CloseConnection

Comment: @TimSchmelter what's wrong with moving the _sqlConn.Dispose into an own method and not doing all stuff directly in the Dispose?

Comment: Ah I see, I also should call Dispose instead of Close (or both). That's what you mean? I updated the question and added the dispose method